# Composer doesn't create symbolic link to bin script

Tags: composer-php

I have problem with composer to generate symbolic link.
I have script in **./bin/my-script** which code looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php echo 'Hello World!'; ?>
```

I have added config in to package composer.json (not in to main project)

```
"bin": ["bin/my-script"]
```

When updating composer in main project my package is installing fine.
However composer not creates symbolic link to my bin script in **./vendor/bin**

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

OK I found the problem.

As I pull from local repository instead composer packages

I had to add below line in to repositories settings in my main project.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "200mph/m-commander",
            "version": "dev-master",
            "source": {
                "url": "/home/wojtek/m-commander",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "develop"
            },
            "bin": ["bin/m-commander"],
            "autoload": {
                "psr-4" : {
                    "mcommander\\" : "src/",
                    "examples\\mcommander\\" : "examples/"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked this link https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/vendor-binaries.md

I think your problem related with following subject :

> What happens when Composer is run on a composer.json that defines
>   vendor binaries?#
>
> For the binaries that a package defines directly, nothing happens.
>
> What happens when Composer is run on a composer.json that has
>   dependencies with vendor binaries listed?#
>
> Composer looks for the binaries defined in all of the dependencies. A
>   symlink is created from each dependency's binaries to vendor/bin.

Comment: That's what I have.
Package have that BIN variable settled.

So If another project required above package the BIN script sym link should be generated.

But is not

Comment: Just to clarify. I did it in the same way as PhpUnit did.

Comment: Could you share your composer.json ? I checked the phpunit by the way, firstly in phpunit directory, phpunit is executable file, it may be an issue.